# Remove readonly attribute from directory

Tags: c#, .net, directory, readonly

How can I programatically remove the readonly attribute from a directory in C#?

Comment: @Lalit What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: see I have read only folder on my some path. I want to copy some files in that folder. so that want to temporary make it writable means remove readonly , then copy files then again make that foleder as readonly. can u help me plaese? This is requirement.

Comment: On Windows, having the readonly attribute set on a directory is actually pretty meaningless. You can still delete, rename, etc. that directory. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/326549/you-cannot-view-or-change-the-read-only-or-the-system-attributes-of-folders-in-windows-server-2003,-in-windows-xp,-in-windows-vista-or-in-windows-7 for more info.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

```
var di = new DirectoryInfo("SomeFolder");
di.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
```

Comment: &= --> Append so dont touch all the other attributes    and   ~   --> complement so do the opposite of readonly

Comment: This may be the correct answer. However, as Alastair commented on the question, you should read https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/326549 before use. It may not do what you think it does. Notice that the "Read-only" option on the File Properties dialog box says, "(Only applies to files in folder)".

Comment: Quick additional note:  You need to Refresh() before you read/update the attributes because directory information is cached. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo.attributes#remarks

Answer (score 9):

Here's a good link to examples of modifying file attributes using c#

http://www.csharp-examples.net/file-attributes/

based on their example, you can remove the Read Only attribute like this (I haven't tested this):

```
File.SetAttributes(filePath, File.GetAttributes(filePath) & ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
```

Comment: @Red Swan: I just tested this to add hidden attributes, and it works just fine with directories too.

Comment: This works for files and directories because a directory is like a special file with the directory attribute set (FileAttributes.Directory).

Answer (score 6):

Using the `-=` assignment operator is dangerous for two reasons:
1) It works ONLY IF the `ReadOnly` attribute is set, thus a test is required beforehand.
2) It is performing a subtract operation, which is not is not the best choice when working with binary flags. The subtract operation works if condition 1 (above) is true, but additional subtract operations will ALTER OTHER BITS in the `FileAttributes` field!

Use `&= ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;` to remove `ReadOnly` flag.

Use `|= FileAttributes.ReadOnly;` to apply `ReadOnly` flag.

Answer (score 2):

If you're attempting to remove the attribute of a file in the file system, create an instance of the System.IO.FileInfo class and set the property IsReadOnly to false.

```
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo("c:\\microsoft.text");
        file.IsReadOnly = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

And the version with everything at once if something did not work

```
        this._path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "My App Settings");

        if (!Directory.Exists(this._path))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(this._path);

            DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(this._path);
            directoryInfo.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;

            FileSystemInfo[] info = directoryInfo.GetFileSystemInfos("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            for (int i = 0; i < info.Length; i++)
            {
                info[i].Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting Attributes to `FileAttributes.Normal` worked for me on both **folders** and **files**.

Comment: The only concern I have with this approach is what if the folder (or file) has another attribute?  If a folder is hidden and readonly, and you only want to make it no longer readonly, your method will make it no longer hidden as well.  That might have unintended consequences.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void DeleteDirectory(string path)
    {
        var directory = new DirectoryInfo(path) 
        { Attributes =FileAttributes.Normal };
        foreach (var info in directory.GetFileSystemInfos("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            info.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;
        }
        directory.Delete(true);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Got it finally. ;)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("c:\\test");

        FileAttributes f = di.Attributes;

        Console.WriteLine("Directory c:\\test has attributes:");
        DecipherAttributes(f);

    }

    public static void DecipherAttributes(FileAttributes f)
    {
        // To set use File.SetAttributes

        File.SetAttributes(@"C:\test", FileAttributes.ReadOnly);

        if ((f & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) == FileAttributes.ReadOnly)
            Console.WriteLine("ReadOnly");

        // To remove readonly use "-="
        f -= FileAttributes.ReadOnly;

        if ((f & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) == FileAttributes.ReadOnly)
            Console.WriteLine("ReadOnly");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Not ReadOnly");
    }
}
```

Comment: we want to remove the readonly flag from it. not just showing whether it is a readonly file/folder or not!