# Check if folder is read only in C#.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am working in asp.net(C#)4.0. Before uploading an image, I want to check that if the folder in which the image has been uploaded is exists or not. If it exists, is it read-only or not and if it is read-only, I want to make it not read-only. How can I do so. Each time when I start my application, the folder is set to read-only. So I want to avoid this problem by checking it all by programmatically.

I did like this...

```
            SaveFilePath = Server.MapPath("~\\_UploadFiles\\") + FileName;
            DirectoryInfo oDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~\\_UploadFiles\\"));
            if(!oDirectoryInfo.Exists)
                  Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~\\_UploadFiles\\"));
            else
            {
                if (oDirectoryInfo.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.ReadOnly))
                {
                    oDirectoryInfo.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;
                }
            }

            if (File.Exists(SaveFilePath))
            {
                File.Delete(SaveFilePath);//Error is thrown from here
            }
```

This code throws an error from the specified place on code. The folder "_UploadFiles" is read only but still its not going in to the if statement to make FileAttributes.Normal

The error is..
Access to the path 'C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\WTExpenditurev01_VSS_UploadFiles\Winter.jpg' is denied.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove readonly of Folder from c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316308/remove-readonly-of-folder-from-c)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use the [System.IO.DirectoryInfo class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx):

```
var di = new DirectoryInfo(folderName);

if(di.Exists())
{
  if (di.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.ReadOnly))
  {
    //IsReadOnly...
  }
}
```

Comment: How can I set it to not read-only..? See my edited question for what I did till yet...

Comment: please search here in SO, there are so many similar questions, try to search readonly directoryinfo and you will find what you need ;-)

Comment: ..Please see the question that I have edited..Still getting an error.I have mentioned error message and my code..

Comment: @Chirag: set the `IsReadOnly` property of the file to `false`: `System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(SaveFilePath);
file.IsReadOnly = false;`

Comment: It's `di.Exists` not `di.Exists()`

Comment: I keep changing the folder's readonly property but the c# code doesn't register it. i.e. that if block with the `//IsReadOnly` wont ever be reached. Did anyone test this? It seems like it isn't possible for folders according to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35337364/folder-directory-read-only