# Determine if Removable Drive is Read-Only

Tags: c#, .net, removable-storage

I am working on determining if a removable drive is read-only using C# (.NET 4.0).  I've read many articles that detail the process for determining if a directory is read-only using the following code that came from [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511592/check-if-folder-is-read-only-in-c-net):

```
var di = new DirectoryInfo(folderName);

if(di.Exists)
{
    if (di.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.ReadOnly))
    {
        //IsReadOnly...
    }
}
```

However, I've tried this method using the root directory, and even though the entire drive is read-only (I'm using an SD Card that is locked), I never make it to the line `//IsReadOnly...`.  The contents of the drive cannot be guaranteed (it could be empty or have many, many files), so testing any sub-directory is out of the question.  I know an easy test would be to write a small file to the drive and catch any exceptions, but I would prefer a different method.

Does anyone know of a good solution to this problem?

Comment: How are you not getting an error. (di.Exists()) should be (di.Exists). Are you sure folderName Exists ? Make sure there is not a problem with the path.

Comment: are you familiar with `WMI` if not here is some good reading as well as a good place to start [Win32_LogicalDisk Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394173(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Ah, yes, I missed the problem with di.Exists() in the code.  I don't actually check to make sure it exists in my code, because I get the drive list from a LINQ query using DriveInfo.GetDrives().  I'll change the code to be correct.