# How to find out if a directory itself is ReadOnly instead of underlying files

Tags: c#, wpf, permissions

The reason why I'm asking this is because .NET sees a folder as ReadOnly if any of the underlying files or folders are ReadOnly. Therefor this code:

```
if (!Properties.Settings.Default.searchReadOnly &&
    (diPath.Attributes & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) == FileAttributes.ReadOnly)
    writeable = false;
```

is always going to set writeable to false.

This is a problem if you need to know if the root folder is ReadOnly.
The My Docments folder is not ReadOnly, but this is what's shown in the properties window:

[image: My Documents properties]

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

I tried to approach you suggested, but Documents still appears to have the ReadOnly flag set.

```
if (!Properties.Settings.Default.searchReadOnly &&
    diPath.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.ReadOnly)) // == true
    searchable = false;
```

How is this possible? What user is executing the code? I assume the actively logged in user? Again, assuming because I can write to the Documents folder, it can't have the ReadOnly flag set.

Comment: This SO thread should help: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511592/check-if-folder-is-read-only-in-c-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

```
var writePermissionSet = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.None);
writePermissionSet.AddPermission(new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Write, path));

if (!Properties.Settings.Default.searchReadOnly &&
    !writePermissionSet.IsSubsetOf(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.PermissionSet))
    //diPath.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.ReadOnly))
    searchable = false;
```

This doens't really confirm the ReadOnly flag for the directory, but it does assure me that the user does not have Write permissions in this directory. It's kinda the ReadOnly I've been looking for :D

Answer (score 1):

this should  help

```
use the System.IO.DirectoryInfo class:

var di = new DirectoryInfo(folderName);

if(di.Exists())
{
  if (di.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.ReadOnly))
  {
    //IsReadOnly...
  }
```

}

**But**

This  state does not mean  read only  it's mean `null state`  which means that the state has never changed and it's the default one.

this state means read only

[image]

**Update**
if you  have some sub folders that are marked  read-only your root folder will be flagged read-only.

So try this check and apply as read-only  to your folder than uncheck and apply and you will  see that is  no more marked as read-only

Comment: I updated my question to reflect on your suggestion.

Comment: That may be so, but I can't ask the end user to apply this solution.
There has to be another way. I'll keep looking.

Comment: in  this  case you should  iterate recursively  on all files and sub folders and make them  not readOnly