# Folder (Directory) Read Only?

Tags: c#, .net, directoryinfo

I have a class named FolderHelper with a method ReadOnly - the aim is to check whether the specified directory is read-only and return a bool true or false.

```
public static bool ReadOnly(string path)
{
    DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);

    if (directoryInfo.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.ReadOnly))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I have set the directory to read-only but the method always returns false - can anyone suggest any reasons why?

Comment: Directories cannot be made read-only on Windows filesystems.

Comment: Look more closely at the [read-only checkbox](http://imgur.com/5sEhR9d)

Answer (score 3):

Readonly flag can be applied to files only, not to directories. If you will try to set this flag on directory using windows explorer - you'll end up with the same result - flag will not be set to the directory but can be set/unset to files it contains. Since flag can't be set to directory - obviously you can't get it from directory.

Probably you need to check write permissions on this directory in order to determine if user can create/modify files contained in this directory. You can use [Directory.GetAccessControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1f66bc2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to check it.

Comment: 1 up. You can mention that the `flag will not be set, but it will be set/unset to all containing files only`

Comment: This has been asked a few times see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410127/c-sharp-test-if-user-has-write-access-to-a-folder

Answer (score 0):

Found this on another stackOverflow article and may be this is what you need to do

[C# Test if user has write access to a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410127/c-sharp-test-if-user-has-write-access-to-a-folder)

> ```
>  public bool IsReadOnly(string dirPath)
>     {
>         try
>         {
>             using (FileStream fs = File.Create(
>                 Path.Combine(
>                     dirPath, 
>                     Path.GetRandomFileName()
>                 ), 
>                 1,
>                 FileOptions.DeleteOnClose)
>             )
>             { }
>             return false;
>         }
>         catch
>         {
>
>                 return true;
>         }
>     }
> ```

Comment: @downvoter...Pls explain so that I can improve my answer