# UnauthorizedAccessException can't be caught

Tags: c#, wpf, exception

I've recently run into this problem, and it doesn't make sense.

the following snippet is real:

```
 try
  {
    File.Create(targetFile);
    //File.WriteAllText(targetFile, $"test {DateTime.Now.ToString()}");
  }
  catch (UnauthorizedAccessException uaex)
  {
  }
```

I have checked it step by step, as soon as i get with the debugger to the "File.Create()" method, the exception rises, and it doesn't enter the catch block, also, if i remove the try-catch, it doesn't bubble up to the calling of the method which contains this.

Anyone got any idea why the try-catch and the bubbling doesn't work?

ps. The location where I am trying to create the file is write protected on purpose, this is just a way to check if it is.

Comment: Where in the program do you have this code?

Comment: Its a quite complex project, this method is called from a background thread when the application is starting

Comment: I'm just giving you an alternative, to check if directory is write only protected, you can check solution on that link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511592/check-if-folder-is-read-only-in-c-net

Comment: @Excalibrus i don't think that will work in all cases for all users with different rights to the directory.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I've made a test application where i try to "confuse" things with BackgroundWorkers that run tasks on main thread that create background threads to run the same try-catch that i posted. And I can't seem to be able to recreate the problem with multi threading nor with 1 thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a mistake.

The exception is actually being caught, if you put anything in the catch block, it does execute.

To be fair the debugger confused me, by showing the exception pop-up right at the calling of the method, but that was solved by restarting the IDE