# Making a file have write access through C#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-8

My application has a folder `Data` which either already exists when the application is run or is created when it runs. My problem is that I can't get it to have write access. When I manually uncheck **Read-only** through Windows file explorer and hit **Apply** and **OK**, it's check I open its **Properties** again! So I'm wondering if there's a way for me to fix that or do it programmatically. The method I have for creating the folder is

```
    private void CreateDataFolderIfNotExists ( )
    {
        if ( !System.IO.Directory.Exists(this._datadir) )
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(this._datadir);             
        }
    }
```

and I'm wondering if the .NET framework has some option for making the folder `this._datadir` have write access either when it is created or retroactively.

Comment: why don't you try it on your own.. you already have the code to `Create` the Directory / Folder now after you create it, try to create a file and write to that folder.. what's the problem here..??

Comment: @MethodMan In my program I'm getting a runtime error `Access to path [that directory] is denied` and I'm assuming it has to do with write permissions. That's ultimately the problem I'm trying to solve with my question.

Comment: The code you posted is fine and is not the cause of the issue. There are [SO posts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316308/remove-readonly-attribute-from-directory) on removing the read-only attribute. Can you rename the directory or create a file in there through Windows Explorer?

Comment: The ReadOnly checkbox in Explorer does not do what you think it does.  Surely the real problem is that the user account simply does not have write access to the directory because he doesn't have write access to parent directory either.  Use superuser.com if you don't know how to fix that.  Or whether you *should* fix that, probably not.